# How to calculate joint distribution probability by randomly sampling from two diffrent tables

Tags: probability

I have two tables. The first one  contains $A,B$ and the second contains  $B, C$. The two tables are independent and I am trying to compute the joint probability distribution $P(A,B,C)$ where $B$ from the first table equals $B$ from the second table by taking a random sample from these two tables.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

I want to show that the estimated joint probability distribution is consistent as the sample size gets larger

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. What do you mean by "random sample from two tables"? Do you mean you draw one row from Table 1 with 1/3 probability each, and one row from Table 2 with 1/3 prob each? But do you also mean that you can only draw rows 2 and 3 from Table 1, because B=2 doesn't appear in Table 2? Annd what do you mean that the estimated joint probability distribution is "consistent"?